# いる or ある for the possession of a living thing

Tags: grammar

We all know that 「ある」is to be used with inanimate objects and 「いる」with animate, living things. However, almost all examples of usage that I've seen thus far is in the context of something or someone *being* there. *There is a cat there*. *There is a man there.*

What happens when it comes to listing the ownership of items? If I were to say that I own a cat, does the rule to use「いる」still apply?

> 私は猫が一匹いる。
>
> 私は猫が一匹ある。

（I get that usually one would use かっています here, but this just for the sake of example)

In this case, the former sounds wrong (at least to me), even though it follows the rule. The latter vice versa.

In another example, what if I don't physically *own* something, but rather have someone?

> 私は弁護士があります。
>
> 私は彼女があります。

Both the above sound correct to me, even though in both example, the subject is living and 「いる」should be used.

Can someone clarify?

Comment: Today, I said 「でっかい魚が**い**る！」 at the aquarium.  When I returmed home and opened the fridge, I said 「でっかい魚が**あ**る！」.

Comment: ある's version is a dated expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't say いる when someone owns something whatever they are but it is used in indicating the existence of something animate. I feel 私は猫が一匹いる is a bit unnatural to me but 私には猫が一匹いる and 私の家(に)は猫が一匹いる would be more natural.

The second your two sentences are unnatural because ある isn't used with animate objects as you know but いる is natural like 私は彼女がいます.

In addition, いる has some meaning like 要る(need), 射る(shoot), 炒る(roast).